# T-SQL: What does the AS keyword mean in this context?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am doing a tutorial that is teaching me how to create a stored procedure.
The AS keyword has meant to me Alias until now, but here, it seems to mean something else. What does it mean?

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspGetAddress @City nvarchar(30)
AS
SELECT * 
FROM Person.Address
WHERE City = @City
GO
```

Comment: It has the meaning of "as follows:"

Comment: The `AS` keyword have a lot of meaning depends on the position, in a `SELECT` a `VIEW` etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AS` here is part of the required syntax of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

(See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql).)

As such it is pure syntax, it has no real "meaning" on its own.

Comment: I guess it's meaning is to have a known delimiter, where ends the procedure(function or whatever) signature and where starts the body.

Comment: It probably makes the grammar easier to parse, as it separates the parameters from the body of the procedure. I *don't think* it would be ambiguous without it, but it's easy to include to keep that analysis simple

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, it's a part of the required syntax, but I think also determine how the `SP` will act, as an `Update`, a `SELECT`...

Comment: @Sami: does it matter? Imo the database just cares about the fact that it is  a stored-procedure. It doesn't look at the sql statements inside, there can be anything, actually you could put a SELECT,INSERT,DELETE and UPDATE,... in this single SP.

Comment: @Caleth: of course it's ambigous, you can put any sql inside of a stored-procedure, without `AS` the DB doesn't know that the last is just a variable in the SP and not a parameter: `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspGetAddress @City nvarchar(30) @thisIsALocalVariable int;`